# Apache: Avoiding users to access 'www.foo.com/subdomain1/'

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I have an Apache server, which main rootwebdir is '/usr/www/users/foo/' and 'foo.com' points there. However, I have some subdomains pointing within their directories:

```
subdomain1.foo.com ---> /usr/www/users/foo/subdomain1
subdomain2.foo.com ---> /usr/www/users/foo/subdomain2
```

This causes me a problem: if anyone types 'www.foo.com/subdomain1/aboutme.html', they find 'subdomain1.foo.com/aboutme.html' with another URL, and I'd like to avoid it.

I wondered if there was any way to avoid this (e.g., showing a 404 page), by using a directive within the '.htaccess' file of '/usr/www/users/foo/subdomain1'.

Any other solution is welcome. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sure, you can certainly create redirection rules pointing to an error document that are coupled with two conditions: the combination of domain name and relative path that is requested. However the question is: _why_ would you want to do that? Why don't you simple keep the document roots separate and all is fine?

Comment: Because my webhost provider gives me access to '/usr/www/users/foo/', and here lands 'foo.com'. If I try to create a new 'sub1.foo.com' subdomain, it would land in '/usr/www/users/foo/sub1'.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite requests to the combination of a specific subdomain and a specific path to a custom error document. That should the easiest:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain1\.foo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^subdomain1 http://foo.com/not-found.html [L]
```

This can be done in a `.htaccess` style file or in the real http servers host configuration. The second option should be preferred whenever possible. `.htaccess` style files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and the *really* slow down the server, often for nothing. They are only provided for situations where one does *not* have access to the real configuration (read: "cheap hosting providers") or where an application requires to write those files itself (which certainly is a security nightmare...).

The version for the http servers host configuration would be slightly shorter and more elegant, since the host is set implicitly:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/subdomain1 http://foo.com/not-found.html [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in any subdomain directory's i.e `subdomain1/.htaccess`  to block access using main domain `foo.com`:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?foo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```